# Visual studio 2015 default additional libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include, libraries

When I make an empty project in VS 2015 it automatically puts these libraries into "additional dependencies":

kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

I have no idea what most of these are for, can they be safely removed?

Comment: _"can they be safely removed?"_ Probably not. These are added for some reasons depending on the project type.

Comment: They are core libraries of the OS, removing ones like `kernel32.lib` will almost certainly result in a linker failure. In any case, any libraries which you do not require any functions from will simply not go into the import table of the resulting binary.

Comment: uuid.lib is for GUID, which is used as a globally unique identifier for anything (`COM` objects in particular) that sits on computers. If you're not using `COM` objects or generating GUID to be used as something unique (like unique name for temporary files), then it's perfectly safe to remove. `uuid.lib` was not added by default until yr 2000, but when `COM` got so prevalent, VS team made it as part of default dependencies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many of them can be safely removed.  Here's a quick rundown of what they are for:

- `kernel32` : Process and thread management, file and device I/O, memory allocation (keep this, the C and C++ runtime libraries and compiler-generated code uses it)
- `user32` : Window and menu management (keep this if using GUI, can remove for console apps)  The base set of widgets (= predefined window classes, like buttons and checkboxes and scrollbars) are here.
- `gdi32` : Drawing (keep this if using custom rendered graphics, can remove if just using widgets)
- *`comctl32`* : Fancy new widgets, like trees, listviews, and progress bars
- `winspool` : Advanced usage of printing beyond what GDI covers.  I always remove it.
- `comdlg32` : Common dialogs, like Open and Save File Dialogs
- `advapi32` : Registry support, user account and access control, cryptography.  I usually end up needing this one, your needs may differ.
- `shell32`, *`shlwapi`* : Taskbar and notification tray UI and more helper functions, like predefined folders and path manipulation functions.  Often useful, but many applications won't need it.
- `ole32`, `oleaut32` : OLE is the basis for ActiveX, DCOM, etc.  Many of the newer OS APIs are COM objects, so you probably need to keep this.
- `uuid` : Advanced OLE usage, probably not needed.
- `odbc32`, `odbccp32` : Database access using a very old and unfriendly API.  I always remove these.

Italicized libraries are not in the default list, but more useful than half the ones that are.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't remove them. These are the libraries that interface with Windows.

You do not need to worry about it. `.lib` are really small, and the `.dll`s they refer to are already present as part of your Windows installation.