# Explanation on additional dependency libs when creating dll project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, dll

when creating dll project in visual studio (2017 in my case) there are quite a lot of libs out into additional dependencies

```
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;
```

Is there somewhere a descriptions why so many are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the libraries that interface with Windows.

For more details about what they are for, I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018689/11872808

`kernel32` : Process and thread management, file and device I/O, memory allocation (keep this, the C and C++ runtime libraries and compiler-generated code uses it)

`user32` : Window and menu management (keep this if using GUI, can remove for console apps) The base set of widgets (= predefined window classes, like buttons and checkboxes and scrollbars) are here.

`gdi32` : Drawing (keep this if using custom rendered graphics, can remove if just using widgets)

`comctl32` : Fancy new widgets, like trees, listviews, and progress bars

`winspool` : Advanced usage of printing beyond what GDI covers.

`comdlg32` : Common dialogs, like Open and Save File Dialogs

`advapi32` : Registry support, user account and access control, cryptography.

`shell32, shlwapi` : Taskbar and notification tray UI and more helper functions, like predefined folders and path manipulation functions.

`ole32, oleaut32` : OLE is the basis for ActiveX, DCOM, etc. Many of the newer OS APIs are COM objects.

`uuid` : Advanced OLE usage.

`odbc32, odbccp32` : Database access using a very old and unfriendly API.